# Combo-box select item in JavaFX 2

Tags: select, combobox, javafx-2

I have one [JavaFX] `ComboBox` that is populated with countries.

My object:

```
public static class CountryObj {
    private  String TCountryDescr;
    private  String TCountryCode;        

    private CountryObj(String CountryDescr,String CountryCode) {
        this.TCountryDescr = CountryDescr;         
        this.TCountryCode = CountryCode;             
    }  

    public String getTCountryCode() {
        return TCountryCode;
    }

    public void setTCountryCode(String fComp) {
        TCountryCode= fComp;
    }         

    public String getTCountryDescr() {
        return TCountryDescr;
    }

    public void setCountryDescr(String fdescr) {
        TCountryDescr = fdescr;
    }                 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return TCountryDescr;
    }
}
```

Then I have my `ObservableList`:

```
private final ObservableList<CountryObj> CountrycomboList =
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                 new CountryObj("United States", "US"),
                 new CountryObj("United Kingdom", "UK"),
                 new CountryObj("France", "FR"),
                 new CountryObj("Germany", "DE"));
```

Then my `ComboBox` which displays the name of the country and the code of the country is for my own use:

```
private ComboBox<CountryObj> cCountry1 = new ComboBox<>();

cbCountry1.setItems(CountrycomboList);

cbCountry1.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new                  ChangeListener<CountryObj>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends CountryObj> arg0, CountryObj arg1, CountryObj arg2) {
            if (arg2 != null) {
                System.out.println("Selected Country: " + arg2.getTCountryCode());
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I auto-select a country, for example Germany, if I only have the code of the country, which is "DE"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Couple of months old question but here is more elegant solution for such type of problems.

Modify the `CountryObj` class and override the `hashCode` and `equals` functions as below:

```
public class CountryObj {
 private  String TCountryDescr;
private  String TCountryCode;        

public CountryObj(String CountryDescr,String CountryCode) {
    this.TCountryDescr = CountryDescr;         
    this.TCountryCode = CountryCode;             
}  
public String getTCountryCode() {
    return TCountryCode;
}
public void setTCountryCode(String fComp) {
    TCountryCode= fComp;
}         
public String getTCountryDescr() {
    return TCountryDescr;
}
public void setCountryDescr(String fdescr) {
    TCountryDescr = fdescr;
}                 
@Override
public String toString() {
    return TCountryDescr;
}   
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (TCountryCode != null ? TCountryCode.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
     String otherTCountryCode = "";
    if (object instanceof Country) {
        otherTCountryCode = ((Country)object).TCountryCode;
    } else if(object instanceof String){
        otherTCountryCode = (String)object;
    } else {
        return false;
    }   

    if ((this.TCountryCode == null && otherTCountryCode != null) || (this.TCountryCode != null && !this.TCountryCode.equals(otherTCountryCode))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }    
}
```

Now in you code if you will execute the following statement, it will automatically select "Germany" for you.

```
cmbCountry.getSelectionModel().select("DE")
```

You can also pass an object of CountryObj to `select` method above.

Answer (score 23):

```
    comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(indexOfItem);
or
    comboBox.setValue("item1");
```

Answer (score 9):

I think the simplest solution is to write an *autoSelect* function that finds the matching *CountryObj* in your ObservableList. Once you find the correct *CountryObj*, tell the combobox to set that as its value. It should looks something like this...

```
private void autoSelectCountry(String countryCode)
{
    for (CountryObj countryObj : countryComboList)
    {
        if (countryObj.getTCountryCode().equals(countryCode))
        {
            cbCountry1.setValue(countryObj);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

This can be further refactored to reusable method for all `ComboBox'es` that take different type parameter:

```
public static <T> void autoSelectComboBoxValue(ComboBox<T> comboBox, String value, Func<T, String> f) {
    for (T t : comboBox.getItems()) {
        if (f.compare(t, value)) {
            comboBox.setValue(t);
        }
    }
}
```

where `Func` is an interface:

```
public interface Func<T, V> {
    boolean compare(T t, V v);
}
```

How to apply this method:

```
autoSelectComboBoxValue(comboBox, "Germany", (cmbProp, val) -> cmbProp.getNameOfCountry().equals(val));
```

Comment: I have use your proposal and it is working perfer. Many thanks.

Comment: Best solution so far.

Answer (score 3):

If both comboBox are from the same Array, assembly column one and two, then they have the same sequence. Then you can use the index.

```
a = comboBox1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(); 
comboBox2.getSelectionModel().select(a);
```

"United States" is on index position 1 "US" also on index position 1 then:

```
comboBox2.getSelectionModel().select(1); // is "US"
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Brendan and Branislav Lazic is perfect, but we still can improve the call to the autoSelectComboBoxValue method :

```
public static <T, V> void autoSelectComboBoxValue(ComboBox<T> comboBox, V value, Func<T, V> f) {...}
```

:)